# Intel XDK : Parse.com integration "Unauthorized"

Tags: parse-platform, integration, intel-xdk, unauthorized

I am very new to Intel XDK and i try to make a very simple app like this in that video tutorial: [Using Services Datafeed in App Designer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/videos/using-services-datafeed-in-app-designer).

But instead of the specific service from Rotten Tomatoes i want to integrate a database i have in Parse.com. For that i followed this video tutorial: "Integrating a New Service"

"[https]://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/videos/integrating-a-new-service",

and at the end the response was: **"Unauthorized"**.

Then i found only [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856310/create-a-web-service-in-intel-xdk-for-parse-com-rest-api-or-dreamfactory#answer-24919380) which comes from Intel's HTML5 Development Forums. I did not get anything either with this. The response was again: **"Unauthorized"**.

And now i am confused and disappointed because:

1. I can't find other resources to help my self
2. I don't want to do it someone else instead of me, but
3. Without a full example, how is supposed to make it to learn?

My code now is similar with this in video: "Integrating a New Service"

In *apiconfig.json*

```
{
  "MyService": {
    "name": "The external service",
    "description": "A great API with an external service",
    "dashboardUrl": "https://parse.com",
    "auth": "key",
    "signature": "apiSecret"
  }
}
```

In *MyService.js*

```
(function (credentials) {
  var exports = {};

  exports.ServiceObject = function(params) {
    var url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ServiceObject';
    params['apiKey'] = credentials.apiKey;
    url = url + '?' + $.param(params);
    return $.ajax({url: url, type: 'GET'});
  };

  return exports;
})
```

And in *MyService.json*

```
{
"endpoints": [
  {
    "name": "classes",
    "dashboardUrl": "https://parse.com/docs/rest",
    "methods": [
      {
        "MethodName": "ServiceObject",
        "Synopsis": "Show the entries",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "Name": "objectId",
            "Required": "N",
            "Default": "",
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The object ID"
          },
          {
            "Name": "text",
            "Required": "N",
            "Default": "",
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The text"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Can someone help me more? In whatever way he thinks best.

Thank you all

Edit:

After the following answer, my problem solved.

"*MyService.js*" file after the correction is:

```
(function (credentials) {
  var exports = {};

    exports.ServiceObject = function(params) {
    var url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ServiceObject';
    return $.ajax({
            url : url,
            headers : {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id' : credentials.apiKey,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key' : credentials.apiSecret
            }
        });
    };

  return exports;
})
```

**@ user1736947:** Your answer was concise and precise, exactly what i needed.
Certainly in the future I will need a lot of help, but for now I can go on my self-education thanks to you.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the authentication keys are accepted is different for different services. The example in the video.. rottentomatoes.. it accepted keys as a url parameter, so we append the key to the url and send it. However, seems like parse wants the keys in the headers (according to [this](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-retrieving))

So the equivalent ajax call will be something like :

```
 exports.ServiceObject = function(params) {
   var url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ServiceObject';
   return $.ajax({
     url : url,
     headers : {
      'X-Parse-Application-Id' : credentials.apiKey,
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key' : credentials.apiSecret
     }
  });
```

This might not fix everything but it will move you a step beyond the authorization issue. Let me know if you are able to retreive the class this way. 
To get a particular row entry, append the url with params.objectID.

Also, the XDK services tab has a parse-similar service ... kinvey. It also allows you to create a database online and retreive it.

Comment: have you any suggestion for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854683/intel-xdk-listview-sort/25857916#25857916)?